# Jquery keep selected value after submit failed with jquery chosen

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am using Chosen Jquery Plugin. I need to keep selected value after submitting form has failed. I have single select with **so many** value. I ended up like this:

```
<select name="fruits" id="fruits" data-placeholder="Choose a fruit...">
    <optgroup label="Green color fruit" id="opt-group-1"></optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Yellow color fruit" id="opt-group-2"></optgroup>
    // keep going until 20 optgroup ....
</select>
```

and using javascript via **script.js** file to display the option value:

```
<script>
    var group1 = ['melon', 'watermelon', 'kiwi', ...];
    var group2 = ['banana', 'pinapple', 'lemon', ...];
    // ....

    var option1 = '';
    for (var i=0;i<group1.length;i++){
        option1 += '<option value="'+ group1[i] + '">' + group1[i] + '</option>';
    }
    var option2 = '';
    for (var i=0;i<group2.length;i++){
        option2 += '<option value="'+ group2[i] + '">' + group2[i] + '</option>';
    }
    // ....

    $('#opt-group-1').append(option1);
    $('#opt-group-2').append(option2);
    // ....
</script>
```

Actually I am using codeigniter and there is so many sample code to keep selected value after submitting form failed with manual code like this:

```
<select name="fruits" id="fruits" data-placeholder="Choose a fruit...">
    <option> </option>
    <optgroup label="Green color fruit" id="opt-group-1">
        <option value="melon" <?php echo set_select('fruits', 'melon');?>>melon</option>
        <option value="watermelon" <?php echo set_select('fruits', 'watermelon');?>>water melon</option>
        ....
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Is there any 'jquery way' to do that?

Answer (score 0):

i think this could work without troubles
adapt your view to something like

```
<select name="fruits" id="fruits" data-placeholder="Choose a fruit..." data-current-selected-option="<?=$this->input->post("fruits"); ?>">
    <optgroup label="Green color fruit" id="opt-group-1"></optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Yellow color fruit" id="opt-group-2"></optgroup>
    // keep going until 20 optgroup ....
</select>
```

and your script js

```
var currentSelectedPostValue = $("#fruits").attr("data-current-selected-option");

function setOptionGroupValues(arrGroup, strTargetGroup)
{
    var option = '';
    for (var i=0;i<arrGroup.length;i++)
    {
        var strSelected = (currentSelectedPostValue == arrGroup[i]) ?   " selected=\"selected\"" : "";
        option += '<option value="'+ arrGroup[i] + '"'+strSelected+'>' + arrGroup[i] + '</option>';
    }

     $(strTargetGroup).append(option);
}

var group1 = ['melon', 'watermelon', 'kiwi',...];
setOptionGroupValues(group1);
```

Comment: Thanks to reply, but it's not working. I just curious, and I think I will use manual code like example code I use, for now. Eventhough that way will make my form submission very messy with lot of option.